# Setting Maxrecievedmessagesize from wcf service

Tags: xml, vb.net, wcf

Basically i have a wcf service that returns a dataset of 2000 records.
When i run the function from an application i get the standard error.

"The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element."

Now i know how to fix this problem at the client end. What i'm wandering is if there is any options i can set at the server that will automatically cause the MaxReceivedMessageSize property at the client to be increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the higher limits for MaxReceivedMessageSize both on the client and the server side in order for them to work.

If I remember correctly, any of the settings for MaxReceivedMessageSize, MaxBufferSize etc. will be transferred to the client's default config file when you do a "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I should reopen this old thread, but searched and nothing came up. And, I cannot yet comment on answers.

Answer does not state where this option is set on the server, and I need that answer as well :-)

Comment: In the web.config of the WCF service in the Binding. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=vs.100).aspx)