# Setting MaxRecievedMessageSize in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack, maxreceivedmessagesize

I have a ServiceStack service that sends and receives a lot of data (syncronization of users between two systems), so I need to set Maxrecievedmessagesize in the clients servicemodel config.

I should be able to tell ServiceStack, that the client needs this, so that when the client does Add new servicereference, this is created automatically.

Where do I set this in ServiceStack?

Might be a dupe of [Setting Maxrecievedmessagesize from wcf service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388985/setting-maxrecievedmessagesize-from-wcf-service) but I'm using ServiceStack.

Answer (score 0):

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) doesn't add any additional usage limits itself, any inherent limits are always from the underlying host, i.e. IIS/ASP.NET - which are overridable with the web.config.

E.g you would use `<httpRuntime/>` to increase the maximum file upload size and execution timeout in ASP.NET. The size specified is in kilobytes. The default is 4096 KB (4 MB). So to set it 50 MB you will need to set it to 51200:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="300"/>
```

Other solutions may also depend on the version of IIS/ASP.NET you're using, e.g. this [MSDN Article provides instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jiruss/archive/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-can-t-upload-large-files-using-iis6.aspx) to fix the **HTTP 413 Request Entity too Large - Can't upload large files using IIS6** error in IIS 6.0:

Comment: This doesn't seem to change the client appconfig? Is it possible to, in the wdsl, have the client configured with a different maxReceivedMessageSize? I'm sure it doesnt have to be a ServiceStack option, but is it possible somehow?